# Cabal won't get a new haskell package

Tags: haskell, cabal, wxhaskell

I tried to get the wxHaskell package using cabal
using:

```
cabal install wxcore --global
cabal install wx
```

But running this gave the following error:

```
>cabal install wxcore --global
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
wxcore-0.11.1.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
sh: runGenProcess: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

What did I do wrong? Is there packages I need to install first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting wx to install through cabal is tricky.  If you're using Windows I suggest downloading their binary package from http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/WxHaskell/Download

Comment: Ok, I got that but it won't let me load the modules properly

Comment: There's an executable in the wxhaskell bin folder that registers the modules for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Wx, but I would expect that you need to install the underlying C library before installing the Haskell packages that depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that is a (poor) warning from the wx package (and its custom configure script) that the wxWidgets library isn't on your system.